# How to use scaletoHeight and scaletoWidth functions in fabric.js to add specific height and width to image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fabricjs

I am creating  a image editor tool.I need to  crop the image to  specified  height and  width  without skewing  it.  i am able to  crop the image by  using  todataurl  method and  resizing  it  to  specified  height and width. but doing so  some  images  are not in proportion.but if  i am using  scaletoHeight and scaletoWidth  method  the  images are in proportion but  the  height is  automatically  changing to  another  value  to make it  proportional. I want to  know  if there  is  a way  i can  use  both  method to  specify  height  and  width  as i need

Answer (score -1):

You can see [example][1]. In this example,image dimensions will be determined using the mouse.

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/a7mad24/5RpLz/
```

Comment: I need  to  find  a way to  hack  through scaleToWidth  and  scaleToHeight.

Comment: @vishak scaleToWidth scales an object to a given width, with respect to bounding box (scaling by x/y equally) and scaleToHeight scales an object to a given height, with respect to bounding box (scaling by x/y equally).

Comment: @vishak you can use scale for To use both.